# C# serial ports improve slow performance

Tags: c#, performance, serial-port, ports

I am attempting to measure the round trip time when I send a single byte out and wait for the returned byte before sending another byte. The round trip time is slow for my application, about 15 ms consistently, over thousands of data points. However, when I implement a delay of 20ms just before sending the byte, the round trip times oscillates between 1 ms and 17 ms every 20 or so samples. Am I doing something wrong in the code that is making the data transfer inefficient and so variable?

EDIT..
The baud rate is 9600. The other values are not specified, they are at the defaults. I actually do have a different code that has the sending and receiving in separate threads, but I am getting the exact same results. I am not running in debug mode.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
public void serserData()
        {

        int[] numarray = Enumerable.Range(1, 255).ToArray();//new int[] {70, 80, 90, 100, 60, 50, 40, 30 };

        byte[] recvbyte = new byte[1]; //1 byte of data coming in
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat <= datapoints; repeat++)
        {

            int rnd1 = rndseed.Next(0, numarray.Length);
            sentnum = numarray[rnd1];

            byte[] writebyte = new byte[] { BitConverter.GetBytes(numarray[rnd1])[0] };
            Array.Reverse(writebyte);
            Thread.Sleep(sleeptime);
            serialPortOut.Write(writebyte, 0, 1); //Send the byte
                                                  //stopwatch.Reset();



            sentelapsmil = mytimer.Duration * 1000;


            while(serialPortIn.BytesToRead==0)
            {

            }
            recvelapsmil = mytimer.Duration * 1000;
            serialPortIn.Read(recvbyte, 0, 1);



                int numback = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { recvbyte[0], 0x00 }, 0);

                if (numback == sentnum)
                {
                    correctbyte = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    correctbyte = 0;
                }

                double elapsmil = recvelapsmil - sentelapsmil;
                sb.AppendLine(elapsmil + "\t " + correctbyte + "\n");

            }
          }
```

Here is mytimer, based on QueryPerformanceCounter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace HighResTimer
{
    public class Timing
    {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out ulong lpPerformanceCount);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out ulong lpFrequency);

    public Timing()
    {
        if (QueryPerformanceFrequency(out freq) == false)
        {
            // high-performance counter not supported

            //throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out startTime);
        }

    }

    private ulong startTime, curTime;
    private ulong freq;

    private bool started = false;

    public void Start()
    {
        // record start time
        started = true;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(out startTime);
    }

    public double Duration
    {            
        get
        {
            if (started == false) return 0;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(out curTime);
            return (double)(curTime - startTime) / (double)freq;
        }
    }

    public ulong GetStartCode()
    {
        return startTime;
    }
    public ulong GetFrequency()
    {
        return freq;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `mytimer`? How accurate is it? Are you running in debug? Why is your read code on the same thread as the write code (ideally it would be waiting to receive before the byte is sent). What baud, stop bits etc. are you using?

Comment: Some interesting info here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e/how-does-serialport-handle-datareceived?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: I have updated my question with answers to some of the questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that I figured out the real problem, -the USB to serial converter with FTDI chip. I swapped it out for a prolific USB-serial and that changed the round trip times to 4-5 ms consistently. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the driver for the FTDI USB-serial and that also reduced the times down to 4-5 ms consistently.